# Pine Editor combining two tradingview indicator scaling problem

Tags: scaling, pine-script, indicator

I combined two indicators but they are not on the same level and one is in very small size.
How can I show them on the same level and size?

Regards.

Comment: can you provide any sample code or screenshots of your issue?

Comment: Yes sure. Combined indicators look like this https://ibb.co/jbdHLNW and there is another indicator at the bottom when I have to zoom in a lot to see it https://ibb.co/XkGBp6Z. Hope I could explain the problem.